Redo My Own Shower?
I have a corner round shower that I've been limping along with for a decade. The doors are falling off. I've replaced them before, but the whole thing is falling apart. I'd consider perhaps redoing the doors and maybe some frame parts, but the model (Maax) is about 30 years old and they obviously don't make them anymore. I have an appointment with Rebath to get an estimate to simply replace it, but everything I've read here says they're going to charge me a ridiculous amount to do it. My question is this: I'm seeing replacement corner rounds or similar at Home Depot from $400-$700. Would it be worth it for me to just try to take out the olde on myself and put the new one in? I have no idea what's behind the shower (likely drywall), that I'd probably mess up if I had to deal with it. If it's something that I could just unscrew & then rescrew on, I could probably do that. If it makes more sense to find a contractor, I suppose that I could do that, but who does that sort of thing: a plumbing contractor? A handyman? Just looking for any help in understanding what I'm up against, thanks.
More info:
It's a fiberglass shower and I don't need to replace the mixing valve, floor, height, or anything like that. Literally just swap in a new unit that's as close to the old one as possible. Of course, I'm sure there are a number of small things that can and will likely pop up. I'm hoping to avoid any drywall work. I have no idea, however, how fiberglass part of the shower is attached (glue?).

"Worth it" is not a question we answer here. That's your call. Matters of opinion are off topic. Please see the [help] and take the [tour], then revise to ask something specific and objective.

Can maybe find the installation instructions online for that model, if you search.  This will at least give you an idea of what is involved in removing it.  What goes online is there forever, so be careful what you post.

no tiles, just a insert, maybe a picture to clear it up

When you say "corner round", do you meant something like this? https://www.wayfair.com/keyword.php?keyword=32+inch+round+corner+shower+door&refid=GX655478243715.%7E&position=&network=g&pcrid=655478243715&device=c&targetid=dsa-19959388920&channel=GoogleIntent&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwo8S3BhDeARIsAFRmkOMJnJhtbFHqRBRVLPqwrotNYknXDnIpky93JaoRDpAeBuuRM5atI5gaAhEWEALw_wcB

Are you willing to spend a month of weekends learning a bunch of skills that are fun and useful so long as you find them fun and are willing to do this stuff yourself in future?  And do you have another shower to use meanwhile?  Your SECOND one will take a day and a half.  You'll save a TON of money in the long run.

If what you have is just a fiberglass shower with a glass door, and the fixtures are working, a good handyman should be able to do it. You might also be able to DIY it, but then you'll need a few specialized tools, e.g. a hole saw to cut the hole where the valve comes through. It's not really difficult to do, but there are a lot of small steps. Shower enclosures, at least the ones I've bought, come with good instructions. They come with a flange that you drill/nail to the studs, then drywall over the flange/lip. That keeps the water away.
I'd only try to DIY it if you have another bathroom to use while you work on this one.
If you already know the model you want to install, look up the installation manual online from the manufacturer, and it will detail all of the steps. That'll tell you if your current skills are up to the task.
If you need to replace the mixing valve, the height of the shower, the location of the drain, trim the floor (tile, wood, LVP?) around it, add framing to screw the shower flanges, or a lot of drywall work, you might need to call several trades, starting with a plumber. It gets really expensive really quick.
